# When using find in Sublime Text, after using finding text in a file, how do I move focus to the result from the keyboard?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I do this: Cmd-F, < text to be found >

I found the text, and I want to edit it, but my focus is in the search field. How do I move focus with the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press escape.

Also, to select multiple occurrences, use ctrl+D.